# Optimizing applications of same project

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I have two application within the same project in FlashBuilder. Each one use a total of 6Mb of assets. It is supposed to each one have more or less that size when built, but both .swf files have about 12Mb.

Another issue is that when building it takes too long in the "building workspace" process. I change a line, run, and I need to wait like 30s to see my results. Very annoying...

Whats going on? :(

Comment: I have the same problem with the workspace, I would be glad, if anybody would give us a tip on this, but I seriously doubt it. Concerning your app-size: Did you check in the "build packaging"-tab, if you include only the assets you need? (Project->Properties->Flex Build Packaging)

Comment: I have the same problem too, i have four years with flex, but never i could solve this. There is some strange with the imports or references between flex components and classes, for example if you have two components, **comp1** and **comp2**, if you are in **comp1** and imports or create references to some object from **comp2**, the final SWF apparently have the binary of both components. In my application i have 100 SWF components and they have the same quantity of bytes.

Comment: Part of the problem, i solved, creating a library and compile it as RSL([LINK1](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf674ba-7fff.html)[LINK2](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=rsl_09.html)).

Comment: I don't understand your question and therefore voted to close.  Can you please clarify what question you're trying to ask?

Comment: Moving to IntelliJ would be a game changer I can tell you...

Comment: @GastonF. Indeed. I found the place where I have a mess of references, and after refactory that point of my project, all swf have the right size now. Phew.